# Group Regex to match until word boundary

Tags: python, regex

Taking the following string as an input example

`Post-Match Thread: Barcelona - Olimpia Milano [EuroLeague Regular Season, Round 24]`

The goal is to get the home team, the away team and the competition in hand. In this case, that would be `Barcelona`, `Olimpia Milano` and `EuroLeague`, respectively. When trying to use the group function, I was able to retrieve both teams just fine (even if a `strip()` call was necessary) but for some reason the current regular expression is not able to get the competition. Several options were tried, with the current iteration being the following:

```
title_group_regex = r"Post-Match Thread: (?P<home_team>(.*?))-(?P<away_team>(.*?))\[(?P<competition>(.*?))\b"
title_group = re.search(title_group_regex, thread_title)
```

In this attempt, I was attempting to match anything after the `[` char up until a word boundary. However this results in `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. I imagine I'm close but lacking that final touch. Thank you.

Comment: `r"\\b"` means ``\`` and `b`. A word boundary is `r"\b"` or `"\\b"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew same thing happens when trying to apply `"\b"`

Comment: `[.*?]` matches a single char, `.` , `*` or `?`. What were you up to? Escape `[` if you mean to match a literal `[`. But `]\b` will only match if there is a word char after `]`. Why use `\b` at all? I doubt your actual problem is related to a word boundary. See https://regex101.com/r/m7Vzyg/1. And the [code generated online](https://regex101.com/r/m7Vzyg/1/codegen?language=python).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was a mistake. I updated the regex and it is now returning an empty string for `competition`. gonna check the link though.

Comment: Please update the question once you know the actual requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the requirements are absolutely clear. they are explained in plain text. the only thing I changed was regex that had an error.

Comment: I guess you just need `\w+` instead of `.*?\b`, use `Post-Match Thread: (?P<home_team>(.*?))-(?P<away_team>(.*?))\[(?P<competition>(\w+))`, see https://regex101.com/r/m7Vzyg/5. Still a duplicate though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's it, thank you so much.